# Discard message from nServiceBus mutator

Tags: nservicebus

I need to discard a message if a specific header is present.

I tried to implement a IMutateTransportMessages and call DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers() method inside MutateIncoming but the message is dispatched to handlers anyway.

I can discard the message using an handler but I don't like it because I need also to specify the handlers' order.

Any solution?

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: What version of NServiceBus are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will be possible from a message mutator. After all, this isn't really the kind of activity a message mutator should be doing - it has nothing to do with changing the structure of the message.

I agree with you that it sounds messy to do this in a handler, because you're right - then you are very dependent upon the handler order.

Discarding a message due to the presence (or absence) of a header is an infrastructure concern, and since you are using NServiceBus V5, the best way to customize the infrastructure is by customizing the message handling pipeline.

Here's [the relevant documentation that covers creating a behavior and inserting it into the pipeline](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/customising) but here's the short version:

1. You need to create a behavior that implements `IBehavior<IncomingContext>`. All of the behaviors together form a behavior chain that progress to the next step by calling `next()` - an `Action` present in the implementation) method.
2. Within the behavior, check for your header. To stop processing the message, just don't call `next()` and call `context.DoNotInvokeAnyMoreHandlers()` instead.
3. Create a class inheriting `RegisterStep` which, from its constructor, will define where in the pipeline to insert your behavior. You could register it right before the `MutateIncomingTransportMessage` step.
4. Create a class implementing `INeedInitialization` (note that this could be the same as the `RegisterStep` class) which calls `busConfig.Pipeline.Register<TClassThatInheritsRegisterStep>()`.

Again, that's the short version. Check out the [docs](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/customising) for the full story and an example.

*Shameless plug: This process is also described in detail in [Learning NServiceBus - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-nservicebus-second-edition) in Chapter 7, with an example.*

Comment: IBehavior<IncomingContext> is what I was looking for. Thanks

Shame plug: I have your book  but I read until chapter 5 so far, my fault!